# Select an information from a row based on the maximum value of specific column in a group by?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I have this data

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Id| Date_Opera | Emitter    |   EmitterIBAN                         |  Receiver    |   ReceiverIBAN                           |         Adresss                          |     Value 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1, | 2017-07-07 | Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0002,        121.72
2, | 2017-09-27 | Keene,         SK81 1004 7484 7505 6308 9259,        Torrance,       RO23 ZWTR OJKK VAU9 T5P4 2GDY,                  35197 Green Ridge Way,                   82.52
3, | 2017-10-17 | Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0048,        51.81
4, | 2017-05-01 | Korie,         ME43 9833 9830 7367 4239 60,Roy,      IL69            9686 1536 8102 2219 165,                        5 Swallow Alley,                         88.01
5, | 2017-11-17 | Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0001,        133.99
6, | 2017-10-10 | Charmine,      BG92 TOXX 8380 785I JKRQ JS,          Sarette,        MU67 RYRU 9293 5875 6859 7111 075X HR,          8 Sage Place,                            36.30
7, | 2017-07-18 | Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point         0004,        186.99
```

And i would like to get a result like this one below

- Calculate the number of operation that a couple of EmitterIBAN and ReceiverIBAN made
- Calculate the sum values for each couple of EmitterIBAN and ReceiverIBAN
- And Group by the addresses that can be different by taking the maximum address value

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sum| Date_Opera | Emitter    |   EmitterIBAN                         |  Receiver    |   ReceiverIBAN                           |         Adresss                          |     SumValue 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4, | 2017-11-17 |  Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point           0048,      494,51
1, | 2017-09-27 |  Keene,         SK81 1004 7484 7505 6308 9259,        Torrance,       RO23 ZWTR OJKK VAU9 T5P4 2GDY,                  35197 Green Ridge Way,                   82.52
1, | 2017-05-01 |  Korie,         ME43 9833 9830 7367 4239 60,Roy,      IL69            9686 1536 8102 2219 165,                        5 Swallow Alley,                         88.01
1, | 2017-10-10 |  Charmine,      BG92 TOXX 8380 785I JKRQ JS,          Sarette,        MU67 RYRU 9293 5875 6859 7111 075X HR,          8 Sage Place,                            36.30
```

So to get this result i use this request

```
Select  count(1) as NumberOperation, 
        MAX(Emitter) as EmitterName, 
        EmitterIban, 
        MAX(Receiver) as ReceiverName, 
        ReceiverIban,
        MAX(ReceiverAddress) as ReceiverAddress,
        SUM([Value]) as SumValues
FROM TableEsperadoceTransaction
Group By EmitterIban,
         ReceiverIban
```

but now, what i want is, instead of taking the maximum address just like the example before, I would like to take the address, from the record that has the biggest data time operation.
Here's an exemple of my data result how shoud look like

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sum| Date_Opera | Emitter    |   EmitterIBAN                         |  Receiver    |   ReceiverIBAN                           |         Adresss                          |     SumValue 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
4, | 2017-11-17 |  Ernst,         HR53 8827 2118 4692 8207 5,           Kimbra,         CH20 1042 6T0N MDTG JT47 U,                     3256 Arrowood Point           0002,      494,51
1, | 2017-09-27 |  Keene,         SK81 1004 7484 7505 6308 9259,        Torrance,       RO23 ZWTR OJKK VAU9 T5P4 2GDY,                  35197 Green Ridge Way,                   82.52
1, | 2017-05-01 |  Korie,         ME43 9833 9830 7367 4239 60,Roy,      IL69            9686 1536 8102 2219 165,                        5 Swallow Alley,                         88.01
1, | 2017-10-10 |  Charmine,      BG92 TOXX 8380 785I JKRQ JS,          Sarette,        MU67 RYRU 9293 5875 6859 7111 075X HR,          8 Sage Place,                            36.30
```

So my question is how can i do such request?

PS: I have 240 million records

Edit : 
I have 3 Index

1. Date_Operation
2. EmitterIban
3. ReceiverIban

Comment: Any indexing on this table?

Comment: yes @JohnHC i have two index in EmitterIBAN and ReceiverIBAN

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like this:

```
Select  count(1) as NumberOperation, 
        MAX(t.Emitter) as EmitterName, 
        t.EmitterIban, 
        MAX(t.Receiver) as ReceiverName, 
        t.ReceiverIban,
        (SELECT TOP 1 x.RecieverAddress 
         FROM TableEsperadoceTransaction AS x 
         WHERE x.EmitterIban=t.EmitterIban AND x.RecieverIban=t.RecieverIban
         ORDER BY Data_Opera DESC) as ReceiverAddress,
        SUM(t.[Value]) as SumValues
FROM TableEsperadoceTransaction AS t
Group By t.EmitterIban,
         t.ReceiverIban;
```

I replaced your `MAX(Address)` with a sub-select fetching the top most address, ordered by `Data_Opera` with the same conditions...

Btw: It would help to place an index on your date column...

### UPDATE: This might be faster...

```
Select  count(1) as NumberOperation, 
        MAX(t.Emitter) as EmitterName, 
        t.EmitterIban, 
        MAX(t.Receiver) as ReceiverName, 
        t.ReceiverIban,
        (SELECT TOP 1 x.RecieverAddress 
         FROM TableEsperadoceTransaction AS x 
         WHERE x.EmitterIban=t.EmitterIban 
           AND x.RecieverIban=t.RecieverIban
           AND x.Data_Opera=MAX(t.Data_Opera)) as ReceiverAddress,
        SUM(t.[Value]) as SumValues
FROM TableEsperadoceTransaction AS t
Group By t.EmitterIban,
         t.ReceiverIban;
```

The `GROUP BY` will allow you to get the `MAX(t.Data_Opera)` directly. With a *three-column-index* you should get your address value very quickly.

Comment: With the subquery, isn't this going to hit the index for each and every line?

Comment: I think the engine will be smart enough to get this inlined... Your approach with `ROW_NUMBER()` might produce some overhead, as you have to pick each and every row, number them and throw most of them away again.   It would help probably to have an index with all three columns and the `Data_Opera DESC`. Thus the engine could pick the first fitting value in any case...

Comment: @Shnugo  I have 3 Index  Date_Operation, EmitterIban ,ReceiverIban shoud i create a index with the 3 column ?

Comment: Check it out, the engine is very smart with such easy constructions (much, but easy). It might help to add a *multi column index* as suggested above...

Comment: @Shnugo i start this morning the request execution and i m waiting for the result. 
in my use case i have to select and insert from 4 table that has the same structure so at the moment 6 hours passed from the beginning of the execution so that why it's took to much time.
I will try the new version tomorrow i think.
I have little question, i have group by for 4 column would it more interesting to make a index for this 4 column ?

Comment: @Esperadoce Poor you... Good luck!

Comment: @Esperadoce Any column, which is used in sorting / searching / filtering will benefit from an index...  You [might have a look here: Finding missing indexes](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345417(v=sql.105).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use window function (SQL 2012+):

```
Select  count(1) as NumberOperation, 
        MAX(t.Emitter) as EmitterName, 
        t.EmitterIban, 
        MAX(t.Receiver) as ReceiverName, 
        t.ReceiverIban,
        FIRST_VALUE(x.RecieverAddress) OVER (PARTITION BY t.EmitterIban, t.ReceiverIban ORDER BY Data_Opera DESC),
        SUM(t.[Value]) as SumValues
FROM TableEsperadoceTransaction AS t
Group By t.EmitterIban,
         t.ReceiverIban;
```

Comment: Good solution (+1), but it's worth to mention, that this `FIRST_VALUE() OVER(...)` is available not before v2012.

Answer (score 1):

I used a row_number() in a CTE, self joining for the aggregates:

```
with CTE as
(
select t1.*, row_number() over(partition by EmitterIban, ReceiverIban order by Date_Opera desc)  as rn
from TableEsperadoceTransaction t1
)

select a1.EmitterIban,a1.emitter as EName, 
       a1.ReceiverIban, a1.receiver as RName,
       a1.ReceiverAddress
       max(a2.rn) as NumberOperation,
       sum(a2.value) as SumValues
from CTE a1
inner join CTE a2
on a1.EmitterIban = a2.EmitterIban
and a1.ReceiverIban = a2.ReceiverIban
where a1.rn = 1
group by a1.EmitterIban,a1.emitter, 
         a1.ReceiverIban, a1.receiver,
         a1.ReceiverAddress
```